# Docker website running locally not loading CSS

Tags: 8

I'm completely new to Drupal, and I'm running this multi-container Drupal-Docker app locally, and website is only loading HTML, no CSS.

These are the only error warnings I am getting.

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "dbname=template1" to address: Name or service

Any help?

Comment: Hey hey, welcome to DA. Unfortunately this question is a little bit out of scope of Drupal Q&A and is better asked on Stack Overflow or somewhere in the Docker community. But I'd suggest you first have a look at one or two of the thousand available Drupal+Docker repos on GitHub. As you are surely not the first one who has problems to have their Docker containers play together nicely :)

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [Docksal][1] as a Docker solution for Drupal.


  [1]: http://docksal.io

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to link the db container. Look at the quickstart here https://hub.docker.com/r/feikede/drupal8-docker/ and take care for the "--link" to your database container.

Comment: Another possibility is, that you don't have write permissions to your public files (default: site/default/files). Check that. Drupal can not create aggregated CSSs then.